# Clean installation of Haskell onto a Windows 10 machine?

Tags: haskell

I just started on Haskell and really love the language! Was looking for some installation help.

I just finished CIS194 and most of the excellent LYAH book. I am currently doing the fp-course recommended here: https://github.com/bitemyapp/fp-course

My issue is that i've done of my work on a mac os laptop up to this point, and now want to do a haskell installation on my windows desktop to work on my larger and more comfortable home setup; however i've struggled to find a method to do a "clean" installation. The haskell platform keeps recommending choclatey which doesn't seem to offer me a choice to change the download location. My issue is that i use a small SSD for my OS drive, and have a large 2TB secondary drive where i would like the installation to go instead.

My other point of confusion is that some people seem to vehemently recommend a stack installation instead of the haskell platform installation; whilst others say it doesn't matter. I'm a beginner so I doubt it matters to me but the haskell platform and choclatey were extremely frustrating as after I installed them, not only was I not able to find a beginner friendly way to change the installation directory, deleting packages/haskell entirely was extremely obtuse and hard to find resources for.

My concern is that over time, this will take a significant amount of space on my smaller system drive, forcing me to reformat again. I'm not sure if a Stack installation will be any better in this regard but I'm hoping for an installation that lets me choose exactly where all the files go.

Many posts outlined an uninstaller that should have come with the haskell platform, but it did not for me and was not shown in my add or remove programs so i had to resort to simply reformatting and am now looking for help before jumping back in (to hopefully avoid doing this again).

In summary, could I have help with doing an installation on a non-home drive, that is very easily removed, with clear knowledge of exactly where all the haskell files are, on a Windows 10 machine? Would really appreciate any help with this!

Comment: Did you try ghcup as I suggested on reddit; did it let you specify the installation directory? Did you try asking the developers for help in the #haskell-ghcup irc channel?

Comment: Hey, thanks for your multiple responses! The solutions you suggested didn't appear to be what I was looking for unfortunately. The link re choclatey allowed me to change the installation location of choclatey, but i'm not sure if that would translate in the future to letting me also change the installation location of Haskell, and the ghcup link you provided also went to a page that just asked me to run a script in a powershell session, which looked similar to the other installation via choclatey. I'm not familiar with IRC so thought to try my luck asking here instead

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The main space-hoggers of a GHC + [cabal-install](https://cabal.readthedocs.io/en/3.4/index.html) configuration are GHC itself and cabal-install's ["store"](https://cabal.readthedocs.io/en/3.4/nix-local-build.html?highlight=store#local-versus-external-packages), the place where it caches compiled packages.

To fully control the installation directories:

- Download the Windows *binary* distribution of GHC [here](https://www.haskell.org/ghc/download_ghc_9_0_1.html#windows64). Decompress the folder (annoyingly, it's in [`.tar.xz`](https://superuser.com/questions/390892/how-to-open-a-large-file-with-an-tar-xz-extension) format) and put the resulting `/bin` subfolder [in your `PATH` environment variable](https://www.architectryan.com/2018/03/17/add-to-the-path-on-windows-10/).
- Download the Windows *binaries* of cabal-install [here](https://www.haskell.org/cabal/download.html). Decompress the program and put its location folder in your `PATH` environment variable

Create an initial Cabal configuration file with this command:

```
cabal --config-file=here-put-your-desired-conf-path user-config init
```

Create an environment variable [`CABAL_CONFIG`](https://cabal.readthedocs.io/en/3.4/installing-packages.html#overview) whose value should be `here-put-your-desired-conf-path`.

(Remember to re-open the terminal every time you create/modify an environment variable. If you change the variables using the [System Properties](https://www.architectryan.com/2018/08/31/how-to-change-environment-variables-on-windows-10/) dialog, currently open terminals might not "get" the change.)

Edit the newly created `here-put-your-desired-conf-path` configuration file and edit the values for the `remote-repo-cache:`, **`store-dir:`**, `world-file:`, `extra-prog-path:`, `build-summary:`  , `installdir:` and `install-dirs user / prefix:` fields, pointing them to new paths. Basically, change anything which points to places you don't want.

---

**Edit:** Actually, there's a better way than working with `CABAL_CONFIG` and having to manually edit the configuration file.

There's another environment variable called [`CABAL_DIR`](https://cabal.readthedocs.io/en/3.4/installing-packages.html?highlight=CABAL_DIR#configuration-file-discovery) that points to some folder and, when specified, puts all cabal files below that folder. It also searches for the cabal config file there. [According to the User Guide](https://cabal.readthedocs.io/en/3.4/installing-packages.html?highlight=CABAL_DIR#configuration-file-discovery):

> 3.1.2.1. Configuration file discovery
>
> If $CABAL_CONFIG is set use it,
>
> otherwise if $CABAL_DIR is set use $CABAL_DIR/config
>
> otherwise use getAppUserDirectory "cabal"

So, just after uncompressing cabal-install and putting its folder in the `PATH`, unset `CABAL_CONFIG`, define the `CABAL_DIR` environment variable, and point it to some existing folder that you want to use (and re-open any terminal so that they see the changes).

That should be enough, no need to explicitly create the config or modify it. All cabal files will be below `CABAL_DIR`.

Comment: THANK YOU!! This is exactly what I hoped for. A slight clarification for anyone as unused to terminals as me, the format for the command is

cabal --config-file="path/to/config" user-config init, for example cabal --config-file="D:/Haskell/cabal/config" user-config init or something. In case anyone in the future in the same situation as me comes across this

Comment: Another option would have been to simply go with de default Cabal config file, and edit that. The location of the default cabal config file is displayed in the last line of `cabal help`. But I chose to be more explicit and set `CABAL_CONFIG`.

Comment: @ChairmanMeow I edited my answer with a slightly simpler method.

Comment: appreciate it! have added that to my system environment as well and will keep this solution saved for future reference :)

Comment: Related discussion about `CABAL_DIR` and its possible deprecation: https://github.com/haskell/cabal/issues/7455

Answer (score 2):

My advice, use `stack` for installing GHC and for project and dependency management. All Haskell's dependencies are under the `stack` folder (global) and `.stack-work` folder (per project), making it clean to remove and check for storage size: Just delete these folders and no trace of Haskell will reamain in your system. (Notice, that the path to the folders are system dependent, so check the documentation for windows installation)

The way `stack` helps you to keep dependencies/storage under control is by using `snapshots`. This is a fixed set of library version. For example:

- [lts-18.0](https://www.stackage.org/lts-18.0) uses compiler version `ghc-8.10.4`. In the link you can see the version of each library.
- As long as you use the same `lts` all along your global configuration and projects configuration, `stack` will reuse dependencies between projects, so you avoid downloading the same library with different version and different compilers too.

The problem with `stack` is that a miss-use of it, can lead to the storage problem you are afraid of. So, before using `stack` be sure you:

1. Read the [user guide](https://docs.haskellstack.org/en/stable/GUIDE/). Most question asked in this site about `stack` are explicitly resolved in the user guide.
2. Again, read the **whole** user guide... I'm serious about this. If you come from python-ish enviroment in which `pip install` solves your problems, you'll find a lot of troubles using `stack` due to project-oriented dependencies over global dependencies
3. Be sure you understand what a `snapshot` (a.k.a. `lts`) is, and how to configure it, otherwise, *you'll end up with many different version of the compiler installed in your computer* (hence, tons of storage wasted).
4. The differences between the `stack.yaml` and `project.yaml`.
5. If you have a **concrete** question about `stack` come back here a post it. Please avoid generic questions like *Can anyone explain stack?*, it is prefered somthing specific and direct to the point. ex: *what is the difference between lts-17 and lts-16?*

Comment: This does not answer the question, IMO.

Comment: @chi OK, you are rigth that I didn't focus on storage enough. My point is, `stack` can help to keep dependencies/storage under control, but you must know how to use it, otherwise you'll be using multiple `snapshots`. The answer needs edition indeed.

Answer (score 0):

This is more of a hack than a solution, but I ended up creating a soft link from the folder that `stack` was expecting on my `C: drive (%APPDATA%\Local\Programs\stack\x86_64-windows)` to my secondary `E:` drive on my Windows machine. Not ideal, but setting the `TMP`, `TEMP` or `USERPROFILE` variables as suggested on the stack documentation FAQ was not changing `stack`'s behaviour.